# How to specify a "Like" on an integer column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

This one has me stumped and thought I would pose it to the SO community for help.

A user wants to select all orders that start with a certain ID, example:

*123* would return *123*, *12345*, *1238790*, etc.  ID is an int column however.

I'm using nHibernate and my line currently is:

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", itemId));
```

but that's only going to return me 123.  I can do a Restrictions.Like, but that converts to a SQL LIKE clause and that won't work on an int col.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry, the DB is SQL Server 2008

Comment: Very odd requirement. Why would the user need such a thing?

Comment: Think about what it means, mathematically speaking, for a given number to "start with" `123`.

Comment: This should be doable casting `id` to string, but that would result in slow performance, since index would not be used. That's weird requirement indeed.

Comment: Have you tried the equivalent of the following (in SQL):  `where cast(id as text) like '123%'`?

Comment: @Oded, The DB could be split with ranges of IDs stored in different places or meaning different things.

Comment: @DanLehmann - "could be". Probably isn't.

Comment: Sorry guys, just added, it's SQL Server 2008

Comment: I agree it's an odd request, I'm going to tell him it's not a good idea.  I was curious what the community thought, some good creative ideas anyways.  I was also thinking the "range" solution as well.  Pretty hokey stuff!

Comment: One use here: bank only stores 6 digits for order number, therefore I need to get the latest one appended with the 6 digits passed back from bank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't specify **what database** you're using (SQL is just the query language....), but if you're on SQL Server (the Microsoft RDBMS product), then you could create a computed column of type `VARCHAR(15)` to hold a string representation of your `INT`, and then just search on that....

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ADD IdAsString AS CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(15)) PERSISTED    -- PERSISTED might not work - depending on your version of SQL Server

SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE IdAsString LIKE '123%'
```

Whether that really makes business sense, is a totally different story..... (I agree with Oded and Matt Ball...)

But since that's a string column now, you should be able to use your `Restrictions.Like` approach in NHibernate as you mention.

Comment: How would that be using hibernate? That's what OP is asking

Comment: @Adrian: OP already said: *I can do a Restrictions.Like, but that converts to a SQL LIKE clause and that won't work on an int col.* - that would work on this `IdAsString` column.....

Comment: +1 Yes, it would, assuming we are talking about SQL Server. Op did not specify.

Comment: Thanks Marc, totally agree it's a crazy requirement, I'm going to tell them to forget about it.  Like your idea though.

Answer (score 3):

> A user wants to select all orders that start with a certain ID,
>   example:
>
> 123 would return 123, 12345, 1238790, etc. ID is an int column
>   however.

It sounds like (pun intended) you may have a couple of issues with your design.

First, although the data element name "order number" may suggest a numeric, order numbers and the like are typically non-numeric (e.g. fixed-width text). For example, the [International Standard Book Number (ISBN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) is non-numeric, not least because the final character can be `X`. Even if all the allowable characters are digits, it doesn't necessarily follow that the values are numeric.

A good question to ask yourself is, does it make any sense to apply mathematical operations to these values? For example, does calculating the sum of a customer's order numbers give a meaning result? If the  answer is no then the values are probably not numeric. Furthermore, given a requirement use an operator such as `LIKE` on the values is a strong indication that they are indeed non-numeric.

Second, there seems to be an implied relationship between the value `ID = '123'` and any `ID` that starts with the same characters. To return to the ISBN example, you can determine whether two different books were published by the same publisher (subject to knowing the publisher's codes) by splitting an ISBN into its composite groups. If your ID values have similar groupings, and you need to query against these grouping, you may find it easier to stores the `123` sub-element separate from the rest of the identifier and concatenate the parts for display only.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how to do it in nHibernate but since intergers are of a limited size you could just append the restriction the check for the possible ranges

The SQL Versions is like this

```
With cte as (
select top 10000000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
from   master..spt_values t1 
       cross join master..spt_values t2)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE
n = 123
or n between  1230 and 1239
or n between  12300 and 12399
or n between  123000 and 123999
or n between  1230000 and 1239999
```

Comment: Nice Conrad, I was thinking about this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is possible in Linq (with NHibernate) it's most likely also possible with Criteria. You just need to convert it to an string/varchar before calling the like. Maybe there is a "convert to string" projection?

In Linq this would simply be:

```
.Where(x => x.Id.ToString().StartsWith("123"))
```

Answer (score 0):

in your mapping for the class you can define a string column that uses a formula to populate it.  the conversion from int to string is done using the formula and you'd query against that without having to change your database.