# CAST integer to string

Tags: jpa, persistence

Currently i am using OpenJPA persistence project, and i have a requirement to search the integer value as String. Earlier in JDBC-SQL i can do it by appending **CAST** in sql query.

```
   SELECT cast(yourNumber as varchar(10)) FROM yourTable
                      -------Or----------
     SELECT * FROM yourTable where cast(yourNumber as varchar(10)) like '%123%'
```

But using JPQL it's not possible to use the CAST, I have read somewhere in documentation that we can use **@Convert** annotation but its too not working with Open JPA.

Please suggest any approach to achieve this functionality.

Comment: If you want to perform String operations on a field I would suggest storing it as a String in the first place. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7633686/1356423

Comment: we are in migration stage from JDBC to JPA so its not possible to change the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CAST, try TRIM:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable where TRIM(yourNumber as varchar(10)) like '%123%'
```